# Beginner on ROS,PIC 16/18

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, i am working to a robot similar to iRobot and i've seen ROS navigation on youtube and i'm impressed. So i what to use it on my robot but i dont know if ROS is compatible with **PIC 16/18 microcontroller** that i am using. Please tell me if i can use it and recommand me some **tutorials**. Have a nice day and thx for help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12943/beginner-on-ros,pic-16/18/) by [Dragos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1759/dragos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is designed to run on full computers; not microcontrollers.

You need a full computer with at least several hundred MB of RAM (1GB is better) and a reasonably fast processor (1GHz+) to run navigation.

You may be able to port [rosserial](http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial) to your PIC and use it to pass control signals to and from a PC running ROS.

**EDIT:**

For Linux, I recommend downloading and installing Ubuntu. It's very easy and ROS is well-supported on ubuntu.

For ROS in general, start with the [ROS Tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

You'll want to either write a custom protocol and driver node to communicate with your PIC, or [port rosserial](http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial_client/Tutorials/Adding%20Support%20for%20New%20Hardware) to the PIC and use the rosserial driver to communicate over a serial port.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5